# Using the __dict__ attribute in __getattr__

Tags: python, getattr

Here is a simple class with a customized `__getattr__` implementation:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        func = getattr(self.__dict__['obj'], name)
        if callable(func):
            def my_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print "entering"
                ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print "exiting"
                return ret
            return my_wrapper
        else:
            return func
```

What I don't understand here is why `getattr(self.__dict__['obj'], name)` is used instead of `getattr(self.obj, name)` which is more concise?

Because as far as I can see what `self.__dict__['obj']` does is invoke the value of `self.obj`. May it have anything to do with backward compatibility?

Comment: It doesn't invoke it - but it does access it. `__dict__` is a low level python detail that probably shouldn't be accessed unless you know what you're doing, so your counter example of using `getattr` would be preferable under most circumstances.

Comment: `self.obj` would invoke `__getattr__` again which would lead to infinite recursion. Using `__dict__` breaks that cycle.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited my question taking this into account. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, the reason for this code to exist – author tried to evade endless recursion loop – to not trigger `__getattr__` by `self.obj`